# How to render HTMLCollection in react(passed as props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in react that receives a `HTMLCollection(10) [div, div, div, div, div, div, div, div, div, div]` as props, and placing the prop directly in the return throws an error. How does one render it such that is can be appended at the end of already existing children

**Poor Example for context explanation**

```
export default function Block {
    const {children, HTMLCollectionChild} = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {children}
            {/*HTMLCollectionChild*/}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**EDIT**

The solution I found that seemed to work best is as follows

```
return(
    <div>
        {children}
        {HTMLCollectionChild
           ? HTMLCollectionChild.map((child) => {
            return createElement(
               child.localName,
              { key: `${generate_key()} ${child.firstElementChild.currentSrc}` },
              createElement("img", { src: child.firstElementChild.currentSrc })
            );
          })
        : null}
```

The only downside was that, I needed to know the structure of the HTMLCollectionChild before attempting to render it

for those needing further reading check [createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) docs

Comment: Might recommend taking a peek at this article: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-render-html-react/

Comment: With map. HTMLCollectionChild.map( item => (<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: item.innerHTML
  }}></div>)

Comment: when I attempt this I get ```Error: Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.```

Comment: what if you use a spread operator? like `...HTMLCollectionChild`

Answer (score 0):

You could use html-react-parser package.

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
```

and then use it like

```
HTMLCOllectionChild.map(item => (parse(item)))
```

For more details regarding the package, go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser